# Harmonic function and complex analysis can't prove a result.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration, harmonic-analysis, harmonic-functions, cauchy-integral-formula

I'm trying to show that given $u:\bar D(0,R)\subset \Omega\rightarrow\mathbb R$  an harmonic function, one has that: $$\forall z\in D(0,R): u(z)=\operatorname{Re}\left(\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_{\partial D(0,R)}\frac{\zeta-z}{\zeta(\zeta-z)}u(\zeta)\,d\zeta\right)\ [\star]$$

Thanks in advance.

My try:

1. Firstly, I've tried expressing the harmonic function using the mean valued proprety derived from the Cauchy formula for $f$: $$u(0)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}u(z+Re^{it})dt$$ and extending on a collection of smaller disks but that didn't work,
2. Secondly I',ve tried to start from th Cauchy integral formula for $f$ and express $u$ as the real part but I can't seem to obtain the term $\frac{\zeta-z}{\zeta}$ inside the integral$\ [\star]$
3. I also tried some calculations with Cauchy-Riemann but it didn't lead anywhere.

NB: I would like to do without the poisson formula, if it is possible.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3437459/42969

Comment: I would like to do without the poisson formula, if it is possible. (i'll add thaht in the question). Thank's for pointing it out.

Comment: Assume $r=1$ and show that for $|w|>1$ the Cauchy integral  $F(w)=\int_{|\zeta|=1}\frac{f(\zeta)d\zeta}{\zeta-w}=0$ and then for $|z|<1$ look at $f(z)-F(1/ z)$ - here may be $f(z)-F(1/ \bar z)$ -  and see what you get by manipulating that and taking real parts

Comment: Another idea is to use that if $f(z)=\sum a_n z^n, a_n$ real to start with, then $2u(z)=\sum a_n (z^n+\bar z^n)$ and then if again $R=1$ so $\bar \zeta=1/\zeta$ on the unit circle, integrate $u(\zeta)$ given by the above, term by term against $\frac{\zeta-z}{\zeta(\zeta-z)}$ and see what you get and show this for the imaginary part too; then generalize to $a_n$ complex by writing $f=f_1+if_2, u=u_1-v_2$ etc